# Edit IEnumerable null on controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I cant use one `List<album>` on this, only on view whitout edit tags, I have one view working good, but I can't edit one list of them.

```
@model IEnumerable<MyMixtapezServerCodeHomePage.Models.album>
@using (Html.BeginForm("FeatureSystem", "album", FormMethod.Post))
{

<table>

    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.feature)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.feature_order)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in @Model)
    {

        <tr>
            <td>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => item.name)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => item.name,"album")
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.name)
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => item.feature,"album")
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => item.feature)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.feature)
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => item.feature_order)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => item.feature_order,"album")
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.feature_order)
                </div>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>





    }
    <input type="submit" />
</table>}
```

CONTROLLER

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FeatureSystem(IEnumerable<album> albums)
    {
        foreach (album album in albums)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                albumRepository.Update(album);
                albumRepository.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

I recieve albums is null, why? Can I edit one list? I only need this.

Answer (score 2):

Use a IList instead of IEnumerable in the view and replace the foreach loop with a for loop.

**Step 1:**

Use

```
@model IList <MyMixtapezServerCodeHomePage.Models.album>
```

instead of

```
@model IEnumerable<MyMixtapezServerCodeHomePage.Models.album>
```

**Step 2:**

Use

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
```

instead of

```
@foreach (var item in @Model)
```

Refer [How to pass IEnumerable list to controller in MVC including checkbox state?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17037925/273646) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has not changed since mvc3

So to have an editable collection you've got to use a for loop, not a foreach, or binding won't work.

```
@for(var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
 {
    <tr>
        <td>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => Model[i].name)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => Model[i].name,"album")
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model[i].name)
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>

  ...
}
```

take a look at [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx), old, but I think not outdated.