# How to pass IEnumerable list to controller in MVC including checkbox state?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, model-binding

I have an mvc application in which I am using a model like this:

```
 public class BlockedIPViewModel
{
    public string  IP { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have a View to bind a list like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<OnlineLotto.Web.Models.BlockedIPViewModel>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
}

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>

        @Html.HiddenFor(x => item.IP)           
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => item.Checked)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IP)
    </td>

</tr>
}

<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Unblock IPs" />
</div>
```

Now I have a controller to receive action from submit button:

```
 public ActionResult BlockedIPList(IEnumerable<BlockedIPViewModel> lstBlockedIPs)
 {

  }
```

But I am getting null value to lstBlockedIPs when coming to controller action.I need to get the checkbox state here. Please help.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Use a list instead and replace your `foreach` loop with a `for` loop:

```
@model IList<BlockedIPViewModel>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{ 
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) 
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].IP)           
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x[i].Checked)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].IP)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Unblock IPs" />
    </div>
}
```

Alternatively you could use an editor template:

```
@model IEnumerable<BlockedIPViewModel>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{ 
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.EditorForModel()   
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Unblock IPs" />
    </div>
}
```

and then define the template `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/BlockedIPViewModel.cshtml` which will automatically be rendered for each element of the collection:

```
@model BlockedIPViewModel
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.IP)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Checked)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.IP)
    </td>
</tr>
```

The reason you were getting null in your controller is because you didn't respect the naming convention for your input fields that the default model binder expects to successfully bind to a list. I invite you to read the [`following article`](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx).

Once you have read it, look at the generated HTML (and more specifically the names of the input fields) with my example and yours. Then compare and you will understand why yours doesn't work.

Comment: Also, the hidden fields and check boxes in the original source code are not in the form's `using` block. That might be a problem.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. In my answer I moved them inside the form to make this clear.

Comment: what about when I have the for loop in a partial view ?

Comment: How can I get this indexing to work, when I want to send back an updated IEnumerable list of a custom class to the controller (changed through a [filter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) )  that is using a table and not a for or foreach? `@model IEnumerable<Laier_It.Models.Company>` with `@Html.ActionLink("City", "Index", new { orderBy = ViewBag.sortByCity, companyList = Model })` which only posts back "companyList=Laier_It.Models.Company"