# passing single model twice or thrice to contoller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am new to asp.net MVC-4 and stuck up while retrieving data from view to controller in case of render single partial view twice on company/create.cshtml

My complex model is as follow.

```
public partial class Company
{
    public int CCode { get; set; }
    public string CName { get; set; }
    public string Addr1 { get; set; }
    public string Addr2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string EmailID { get; set; }
    public string Remarks { get; set; }


    public CompanyContacts Contacts { get; set; }
    public partial class CompanyContacts
    {
        public int refCCode_Company { get; set; }
        public int SrNo { get; set; }
        public string ContactPerson { get; set; }
        public string Designation { get; set; }
        public string Contact1 { get; set; }
        public string Contact2 { get; set; }
        public string EmailID { get; set; }
        public string IsActive { get; set; }
    }
}
```

where in the CompanyContact is partial view rendered twice in company/create.cshtml page.

> "@model ProjectName.Models.Company" so that i can bind HTML control as follow. @HTML.TextBoxFor(model >= model.CompanyContact)

```html
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="contacts">
      <div class="col-md-6">
             <p>
                   @Html.Partial("_LedgerContactsPartial")
             </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
             <p>
                   @Html.Partial("_LedgerContactsPartial")
             </p>
      </div>
</div>
```

while save the data, how do i pass two contact person details to controller.

Thanks in Adv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass list of contact person details to controller. to achieve this you could follow naming convention for input fields that the default ModelBinder expects to bind to a list.

[This article by Phill Hack shows Model Binding To A List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/).

And take look to this question  [How to pass IEnumerable list to controller in MVC including checkbox state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037858/how-to-pass-ienumerable-list-to-controller-in-mvc-including-checkbox-state).

Comment: Sorry, i am using MVC4 and it would be glad if you could provide some link for the same.

Comment: Solution is same for MVC4.

Comment: Hi, I went through the same again and it is exactly the same what i am looking for. Thanks :)