# Send data to a View and display it

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My issue is the following:

I can not send my data for display in my view.

First, you must know that I connect to an external Filemaker DB and that the "results" variable retrieves this data.

"results" is of type IEnumerable .

For the recovery part, results contains my model that he found.

But it seems that I'm missing a piece of code because my view does not show any data.

Indeed, my goal is to send existing data into a form.

Could you help me?

**Controller**

```
   [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("idMember", 26);

        List<Models.Members> list = new List<Models.Members>();
        Models.Members m = new Models.Members();
        m.Member_NameFirst = "test1";
        Models.Members m2 = new Models.Members();
        m2.Member_NameFirst = "test2";
        list.Add(m);
        list.Add(m2);
        IEnumerable<Models.Members> members = list;
        return View(list);
    }
```

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<Members>


@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(o => item.Member_NameFirst)
}
```

Comment: If **results" is of type IEnumerable**, why is your view not strongly typed to a collection type ? Are you getting an error now ( about the passed data type not matching than what the view is expecting) ? What is happening now ?

Comment: I only receive this error: jquery.js:9600 GET https://localhost:44338/Members/GetMember/ 500

Comment: That means your `GetMember` method is crashing. Check the response tab of the ajax call to see the details/ put a breakpoint in your method and see which line is crashing.

Comment: it crashes when he hit : xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null );
Dont know how to solve it :/

Comment: Ofc you are right! So i guess i need to declare to my view: @model List<jak.formulaire.Models.Members> ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this for your result:

```
@model IEnumerable<BlockedIPViewModel>
```

Ref. [How to pass IEnumerable list to controller in MVC including checkbox state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037858/how-to-pass-ienumerable-list-to-controller-in-mvc-including-checkbox-state)

This is my successful example.

Class:

```
namespace Test.Models
{
    public class Members
    {
        public string Member_NameFirst { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // Test data
    List<Members> list = new List<Members>();
    Members m = new Members();
    m.Member_NameFirst = "test1";
    Members m2 = new Members();
    m2.Member_NameFirst = "test2";
    list.Add(m);
    list.Add(m2);
    IEnumerable<Members> members = list;
    return View(list);
}
```

[Index] View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Test.Models.Members>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(o => item.Member_NameFirst)
}
```

Be careful of your view @model as well.