# Pass IEnumerable to View and Display It

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-pages

I have an entity class `Owners` that requires an associated class `Cars` to be linked with it:

```
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(32)]
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Cars AssociatedCar { get; set; }
```

The model I am using within my Razor page is my Owner:

```
@model Dealership.Domain.DatabaseContext
```

I'm using the scaffolded Razor pages as a base but they did not create a dropdown to choose a car to be linked with an owner. I have been able to get the selection view on my end using a private enumerable class within my controller:

```
    private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetAllCars()
    {
        var Cars = _carData.GetAllCars().Result;

        var List = Cars.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.Id.ToString(), Text = x.Name });

        return new SelectList(List, "Value", "Text");
    }
```

I then have it set within the scaffolded get controller:

```
    // GET: Buttons/Create
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        var cars = GetAllCars();
        return View(cars);
    }
```

My question is how to I get the cars to show up onto a page through the variable? If it can't be done is there another way to add the Cars to the View? I am very new to Razor and unsure if it's possible using the scaffolded pages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass IEnumerable list to controller in MVC including checkbox state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037858/how-to-pass-ienumerable-list-to-controller-in-mvc-including-checkbox-state)

Comment: Sorry, It does not, I added the Model and will add the Razor code to make the question clearer.

Comment: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding

Comment: You are sending `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` to the view and expecting `@model Dealership.Domain.DatabaseContext` in the view? How would that be possible?

Comment: This code is what was scaffolded... please let me know if this change and what to change it to. As stated I am new to Razor and not sure if scaffolding this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching and learning more about Razor, I figured the easiest way to accomplish this was to create a view model containing an `IEnumerator<Cars>`, a `SelectedItem SelectedCar` and `OwnerModel Car`. I then initialized the new view model in the controller and was able to pass along the data.